# Arbitrary / Ambiguous closure, no explanation

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, close-reasons

This question [How to deploy code through Jenkins and Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59120972/598141) was marked as Closed - off-topic. There was no explanation provided to the OP. I then noticed a similar question that remained open and answered. I raised a question for the moderator to explain how the two differ and why this was closed and to consider re-opening.

I then raised a flag - in need of moderator intervention to get that response. That in turn was declined - and I believe my original comment was also deleted, noting "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention "

That is exactly what I was asking for - moderator intervention to explain why this question was closed in contrast to another near identical question and a multitude of others which are even more obviously "off-topic" or already answered.

Now there's the original question that is not explained and also the question of how the flag was inappropriate that are not explained.

I don't believe declining to provide explanations is going to elevate the level of questions or provide guidance for future actions. I have no doubt the OP is confused and disappointed, as am I in this form of "moderation".

Why to the OP and why to the flag please ?

ps: was the original comment also arbitrarily deleted ?

Comment: Just to clear up a comment you made on the question, no one "moderator" closed the question. 5 users with the privilege to close the question voted to do so. that said i do find it weird that any custom close reason (if any were mode, mods can see if that's the case) have also been deleted

Comment: *was the original comment also arbitrarily deleted* I'm quite curious, what original comment are you referring to? Do you remember seeing a comment there that isn't present anymore? The lack of a reason given (which *is* a problem IMO) *may* be due to a bug in the new post notices, which I've asked [the guy in charge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337013/new-post-notices-rollout-on-stack-overflow#comment1133614_337026) about.

Comment: My original comment is the same one that starts "To the moderator who closed as off-topic ..." I made the comment, then flagged to post for mod attn, so I know it was there. I then added the "admittedly" comment. I know it was deleted as I still had it onscreen on my PC browser (took a screenshot), but the refreshed page on the mobile showed the notification of the decline and no longer showed the first Comment. I copy/pasted it back as-is.

Comment: Regarding your PS: Your comment was deleted because it was not needed, and was doubly wrong. It claims a moderator closed the question (a moderator was not involved), and it defends reopening the question by claiming "there are other questions that are not closed", which is not a reason to keep a question open. If you know of other questions that deserve closure, flag those. Your comment was very likely flagged as "no longer needed", as it's not helping the OP to improve their post in any way, and the flag was honoured. If a comment of yours was deleted by a mod, please do not repost it.

Comment: I think your counter exemple question is bad. As a counter example and as a question. When you find bad question you should see if it fit any reasonable close reason. Too broad, opinion based, looking for off site ressource etc. Because that's how curation works. A new question doesn't give immortality to a bad one just because they look similar.

Answer (score 11):

In the old UI for closing as off-topic, the off-topic reason is also listed. I find it sub-optimal that, in the new UI this is left out...

FWIW the actual close reason is obvious, on reading the question: it specifically requests an off-site resource, such as software or a library.

It also asks about "the best way", which is generally interpreted as "opinion based", also a close reason.

Comment: From https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/337026 it sounds like the reason is *supposed* to be displayed if at least two users chose the same reason when VTCing. That sounds pretty unlikely here, but not impossible. Either that, or someone used a custom reason that others also voted for, which was added as a comment, and that comment was later deleted

Comment: The official source for Jenkins plugins, which is what the OP is asking about- a plugin -  is https://plugins.jenkins.io. Meanwhile [this other post's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59131059/598141) response is also an off-site resource. many of the questions I have answered deal with referring ppl to plugins or their usage. Am I wrong to answer such?

Comment: Agree  "the best way", can be interpreted to be "opinion based". Or, perhaps a non-native English speaker is asking, "which way is right",  "which way is preferred", "is there a right way", or even  "is there a difference for which you can explain the pros/cons". Not wanting to put words in the OP's mouth, but I could edit to rephrase and then provide a pros/cons response, but why would I go that far?

Comment: @IanW Either of those variants would also result in "opinion based". And yes, it is bad to answer to off-site resources requests, since those questions are off-topic. The appropriate course of action is to vote/flag for closure.

Comment: @IanW "*which way is right*" - same thing as "best", what do you define as right? It's opinion based. "*which way is preferred*" again opinion based. "*is there a right way*" the answer is either "no" or Too Broad as there may be too many right ways. "*is there a difference for which you can explain the pros/cons*" same, yet again. All in all, it's the unconstrained nature of the answers that's the problem. Without guiding criteria, anything from a literal single-word "Yes" to a 10k word essay fits. And both of these could even be *wrong* for OP's case.

Comment: @IanW If another post asks for off-site resources then it should also be closed, regardless if it has gotten an answer/answers. There are always users who do not know (or prefer not to respect) the site guidelines for maintaining site quality. In order to help the asker, it's fine to post such links *in a comment*, while still flagging/voting to close as off-topic. That can immediately assist the OP, while not "cluttering" the site with a link/information that *may* no longer be valid in the future.

Comment: @Ianw "Why would I go that far?" As others have commented, the problem isn't so much the phrasing as what the OP (apparently) wants. The time to edit a question is when doing so will provide a useful Q&A for the site. While many people consider and use SO as a "help desk" or tutorial service, that's not the *stated purpose* of the site. As is often said, here on Meta, it's a question of *expectations*: what askers want and what the site offers is often not the same thing. We, as people supporting others, need to make certain choices...

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks for the explanation, and the link to the SE Meta post :-) Not sure whether this is an optimal design...

Comment: Two close votes for an off-topic recommendation question, two close votes for “needs moar focus”, and one close vote for “needs details/explanations”. So, no consensus was reached. I agree that this new close notices system is extremely sub-optimal. I cannot tell what is what, and “needs more focus” is *way* less clear than what we used to have.